# What's the difference between a "delegator" and "delegatee"?

Tags: differences, er-ee

I've seen both *delegator* and *delegatee* used interchangeably in a conversation, and it always leaves me ambivalent to which is correct to use, and when or under what circumstances/context?

It would be nice if someone could point out the difference between the two, and an example would also be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delegator, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delegatee

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suppose *delegator* is a thing or person that delegates something. And *delegatee* is to whom something is delegated. Delegator is a source and delegatee is a target.